# shortcut to delete whole line (not just in bash)

Tags: shortcut-keys

On MacOS, if you press cmd + backspace, the whole line gets deleted. I know you can do this in bash on Ubuntu by pressing ctrl + K, but would like to do this in other applications as well. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Such a command is often specific for a particular tool or group of tools. In which tools do you need this feature? (ctrl + K works in the editors nano and emacs, not only in bash).

Comment: Chrome, Teams, IntelliJ, PyCharm, etc... So a global one would be best, like in MacOS

Comment: You can use: `Ctrl +C` to go to a new blank line, without executing what you already typed.